# Kibana service not running ever after the service has been started in linux

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I have installed kibana in my linux machine. When I started the service using "`service kibana start`" the console shows the message `Kibana started` but when checking the status, it shows `Kibana is not running`.

When I checked the error log of kibana (/var/log/kibana/kibana.stderr), it got the below message

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/local/mnt/workspace/ELK/KIBANA/LOG'
    at Error (native)
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/local/mnt/workspace/ELK/KIBANA/LOG'
    at Error (native)
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/local/mnt/workspace/ELK/KIBANA/LOG'
    at Error (native)
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/local/mnt/workspace/ELK/KIBANA/LOG'
    at Error (native)
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/local/mnt/workspace/ELK/KIBANA/DATA/uuid'
    at Error (native)
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.writeSync (fs.js:796:20)
    at SyncWriteStream._write (fs.js:2244:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:333:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:319:5)
    at SyncWriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:245:11)
    at KbnLoggerJsonFormat.ondata (_stream_readable.js:555:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at KbnLoggerJsonFormat.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at KbnLoggerJsonFormat.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at KbnLoggerJsonFormat.Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:128:32)
    at KbnLoggerJsonFormat._transform (/usr/share/kibana/src/server/logging/log_format.js:74:10)
    at KbnLoggerJsonFormat.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
    at KbnLoggerJsonFormat.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:333:12)
FATAL { Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.writeSync (fs.js:796:20)
    at SyncWriteStream._write (fs.js:2244:6)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:333:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:319:5)
    at SyncWriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:245:11)
    at KbnLoggerJsonFormat.ondata (_stream_readable.js:555:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at KbnLoggerJsonFormat.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at KbnLoggerJsonFormat.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at KbnLoggerJsonFormat.Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:128:32)
    at KbnLoggerJsonFormat._transform (/usr/share/kibana/src/server/logging/log_format.js:74:10)
```

Kibana service was working perfectly in my machine. For some reasons, i have restarted the service and the above error is preventing kibana from starting the service. Kindly give the direction.

Comment: I'll say that the error is evident **ENOSPC: no space left on device, write**

Comment: ...and also `EACCES: permission denied`